# Fatal Error: Call To A Member Function Fetch_Assoc() On A Non-Object

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a small form for people to come to my website and simply enter the following information:

- Name
- Surname
- Email Address

It should send this information back into my table from my database.

Now here is where things get "complex" (...well it is to me, okay? )

If the email address does exist in our table, then it must echo "Email Address Added. Thank you!". Otherwise if it does NOT exist, then it must echo "Email address already exists!"

For some reason it is not doing this. It is spitting out this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\addemail.php on line 46
```

I have attached my php code (below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">

<head>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function redirect () { setTimeout("go_now()",3000); }
function go_now ()   { window.location.href = "newsletter_frame.html"; }
//-->
</script>

<!-- This is the link to the external CSS file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">

<!-- This is the link to the external Javascript file-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>

<title>Page</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="verify-v1" content="gDSxHR1Tk8vWtty9GoRHABGFEH+Bh2VHYCHv0Cx1/Ek=">
<meta name="copyright" content="Burger man">
<meta name="keywords" content="afro, afrodeep, soulful, funky, deep, vocal house, broken beats, disco">
<meta name="description" content="Burgers and chips">
<meta name="page-type" content="Information">

</head>
    <body  onLoad="redirect()" id="iframe_newsl_spec">

        <?php
            $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'si_store') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

                if ( isset($_POST['email_address']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) )
                    {
                        $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
                        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                        $surname = $_POST['surname'];

                        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE email_address = '$email_address'");

                        if ( mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
                        {
                            echo 'Email address already exists!';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mysqli_query("INSERT INTO email_list(email_address, firstname, surname) VALUES ('$email_address','$firstname','$surname')");

                            echo 'Email Address Added. Thank you!';
                        }   
                    }

            //mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error connecting to database.');

            mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you doing ? `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` ? Choose one

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking at. You have an incompatible mix of mysql_() and mysqli_(), and no call to mysqli::fetch_assoc() anywhere.

Comment: Try changing mysql_num_rows to mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Little note: the reason you use mysqli over mysql (and your are not doing it) is prepared statement : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Yes, `mysqli_*` is the first step to sanity, but without prepared statements, Bobby Tables is still going to have a lot of fun

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fixed the `mysql_*` functions, and changed them to `mysqli_*`, *and* you've altered your code so that you use *prepared statements*, you should add the following code:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare('SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE email_address = ?');
//BTW, if all you want to check if a record exists, don't use SELECT *
//Just select one field, not the entire row
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$_POST['email_address']);
//bind param, to statement, as String, value ^^
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//execute the query
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$col1,$col2,$col3);
//bind variables that will be assigned the value of the fields
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{//get the values in question
    echo 'col1: '.$col1.'<br/>col2: '.$col2.'<br/>col3: '.$col3.'<br/>';
}
```

To get an associative array of the result set, you're going to have to [read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) there are a couple of functions there you might want to use.